# Class object gets unexpected argument error

Tags: python-3.x, python-class

I'm new to Python and am trying to code Python classes. But in the following, I get "unexpected argument" error, for the attributes of car_1, car_2 and car_3 (in bold). How to correct it? Or is it a Pycharm issue? Thanks!

```
import random


class Vehicle:
    def _init_(self, make, model, year, weight):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
        self.weight = weight


class Car(Vehicle):
    def _init_(self, make, model, year, weight, is_driving=True, trips_since_maintenance=0, needs_maintenance=False):
        super().__init__(make, model, year, weight)
        self.is_driving = is_driving
        self.trips_since_maintenance = 0
        self.needs_maintenance = needs_maintenance

    def drive(self):
        drive = 0
        if drive > 0:
            self.is_driving = True

    def stop(self):
        stop = 0
        while self.drive():
            stop += 1
            break
            self.is_driving = False
            self.trips_since_maintenance += 1
            if self.trips_since_maintenance >= 100:
                self.needs_maintenance = True

    def repair(self):
        self.needs_maintenance = False
        self.trips_since_maintenance = 0


def randomly_drive_car(car):
    drive_times = random.randint(1, 101)
    for i in range(drive_times):
        Car.drive()
        Car.stop()


**car_1 = Car('Honda', 'City', '2018', '1153 kg')
car_2 = Car('Toyota', 'Altis', '2018', '1745 kg')
car_3 = Car('Mazda', '_3', '2020', '1260 kg')**

randomly_drive_car(car_1)
randomly_drive_car(car_2)
randomly_drive_car(car_3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all correct except that you need to put two underscores for *init* methods.

```
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, make, model, year, weight):
       ...

class Car(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self, make, model, year, weight, is_driving=True, trips_since_maintenance=0, needs_maintenance=False):
    super().__init__(make, model, year, weight)
```

EDIT:
At line 42/43 you're calling 'Car.drive', you should be calling 'car.drive()' (lowercase C) because your function parameter is called 'car'. By using `Car.drive()` you're trying to call the drive method as a class method.

EDIT 2 (from comments):

```py
import random

class Car(Vehicle):

    ...

    def take_trip(self):
        self.trips_since_maintenance += 1
        if self.trips_since_maintenance >= 100:
            self.needs_maintenance = True


def randomly_drive_car(car):
    drive_times = random.randint(1, 101)
    for i in range(drive_times):
        car.take_trip()


car_1 = Car('Honda', 'City', '2018', '1153 kg')
car_2 = Car('Toyota', 'Altis', '2018', '1745 kg')
car_3 = Car('Mazda', '_3', '2020', '1260 kg')

randomly_drive_car(car_1)
randomly_drive_car(car_2)
randomly_drive_car(car_3)
```

Comment: Thanks! Made the correction, but now `randomly_drive_car` doesn't seem to work. I already change the assignment `drive = 0` to `drive_times =0` at `drive(self)` but there is no randomized count of `trips_since_maintenance` no matter how many times I run it.

Comment: I think you can merge stop() and drive() into one method. I don't really see a point of having them seperate.

Comment: All you're doing is keeping track of how many trips you've taken and based on that decide if you need maintenance. You can put this all in one method and that's pretty much all you need.

Comment: Got you and I made edits to simplify the functions. Thanks again.

Comment: In my case __init__ was auto typed to __int__